# How to convert Django bytes data to mp3 files

Tags: python, reactjs, django, axios, webm

I have send audid/webm bytes from react to django.

the code in view.py is like this

```
def get_audio(request):
    audio = BytesIO(request.body)
    print(audio.read())
    print(type(audio.read()))

    # os.makedirs('./data/audio.wav', exist_ok=True)
    # with open('./data/audio.wav', mode='bx') as f:
    #     f.write(audio.read())

    return HttpResponse("audio delievered")
```

the request in react is like this

```
setTimeout(() => {
          setRec("Stopped")
          const tracks = stream.getTracks();
          tracks[0].stop();
          mediaRecorder.stop()
          // console.log(chunks[0])
          
          blobAudio = chunks[0]
}, 5000);
```

```
const audioUpload = () => {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("audio_5sec", blobAudio);
  try{
    axios.post("/uploading_audio", fd,
      {
      headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

now i want to convert audio.read() bytes to mp3 in django directory and write it.
How can i do this?
The above comment parts doesn't work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

Your code creates a directory `data/audio.wav` recursively and then tries to open the file `audio.wav` but `audio.wav` is a directory not a file.

Do this instead:

```
def get_audio(request):
    audio = BytesIO(request.body)
    os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True) # create a directory 'data', fail if the directory already exist.
    with open('./data/audio.wav', mode='bx') as f: # open a file object 'audio.wav', fail if the file object already exists.
        f.write(audio.read())
    return HttpResponse("audio delivered")
```

Comment: For posterity, the OP doesn’t handle [`FileExistsError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileExistsError) exception for reasons unclear to me at the moment (probably handled it elsewhere). You should consider handling it in your case.

Comment: To clean up the the directory created before, add near the beginning: `if os.path.isdir('data/audio.wav'): os.rmdir('data/audio.wav')`. It's enough to run it once.

Comment: Thanks you for solving the file existing problems further,
however now im facing that the .wav file has no data in it.
Is there any problems with writing audio.read() format?